# What are the current issues with Ember Data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've been doing a bit of reading lately on ember.js, and one item that keeps coming up is that there are "issues" with ember-data, and it is "not production ready".

While I keep seeing that, I've never actually come across a list or description of any real issues!

I'm wondering if someone could just provide the 2 second version of what the major issues are currently?

Comment: for a list of issues: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues?labels=&milestone=1&page=1&state=open I don't think this question has a definite answer as the API is constantly changing and soon these issues will go away. New issues will likely appear and the answer will not reflect the state of the API in the future.

Comment: Agree with you on the definite answer, I was mostly just looking for a "state of the union" so to speak.  Thanks anyway